# Converting an integer vector into a vector of byte arrays then calling each byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, types, type-conversion

I have a vector of numbers ex. `vector<int> vec={16383 1 8192}`. I need to convert them to byte arrays so that an SPI write function can read it and transfer data. I can't get a vector of byte arrays to work however. I'm new to C++.

Basically, in case my code is unclear (which it probably is), I want to go from

`std::vector <int> output={16383,1,8192};`

to

`std::vector <byte array> finalbuffer= {{0,63,255},{0,0,1},{0,32,0}};`

so I can call `finalbuffer[0]` and it would contain `{0,63,255}`.

I've tried looking up this problem, but the answers have been in float and not exactly what I need. I tried making an multi-dimensional array, however my initial vector size is not always the same and depends on data being read in.

```
std::vector <int> output={16383,1,8192};

//the basic code to convert from integer to byte array, I don't know how 
// to convert the int vector to a byte array vector 
uint8 tx_buffer1[3] = { 0,0,0 };
   for (unsigned i = 0; i < output.size(); ++i) {
         for (unsigned j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
              tx_buffer1[j] = (output[i] >> (2 - j) * 8) & 0xFF;                     
              cout << unsigned(tx_buffer1[j]) << endl;               
              } 
}

//The above works such that
int output=16383;
uint8 tx_buffer1[3] = { 0,0,0 };
for (unsigned j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
      tx_buffer1[j] = (output >> (2 - j) * 8) & 0xFF;                    
       cout << unsigned(tx_buffer1[j]) << endl;              
        }   
tx_buffer[0]=0
tx_buffer[1]=63
tx_buffer[2]=255
// But I need it for multiple integers from the vector.
```

The below works with `uint8 finalbuffer= {0-255,0-255,0-255}`. `handle`, `&transfercount` and `options` are unimportant. The 3 means it reads bytes, I need it so that the it will read an vector with a byte array in each element

```
std::vector <byte array> finalbuffer= {{0,63,255},{0,0,1},{0,32,0}};

//finalbuffer[0] would contain {0,63,255}

//finalbuffer[1] would contain {0,0,1}

//...

for {unsigned i=0; i<finalbuffer.size(); ++i) {
status = SPI_Write(handle, finalbuffer[i], 3, &transferCount, options);
            if (status != FT_OK)
                print_and_quit("Error while transmitting bytes.");
}
```

I can't get my code to work. Is a better way of doing it that isn't a byte array vector?

Comment: vectors of C arrays are not legal, so it's no surprise you can't get it to work.

Comment: Three-byte integers? That's pretty unusual. Anyway, it's just a matter of masking and shifting.

Comment: You'll be surprised to learn that you already wrote 95% of the code to do this. The only thing that's missing is creating a `std::vector<char>`, and instead of  dumping each byte to `std::cout`, just `push_back`() it into the char vector. Seems pretty obvious.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would rather recommend `std::vector<byte>` or `std::vector<uint8_t>` for the byte-vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I somehow understand, but not fully. Maybe my answer is therefore not accurate.

But first of all, you want to convert a vector with ints into a vector of something with 3 bytes.

For the something with 3 bytes we will use a std::array of bytes with size 3. And we will use unsigned for everything.

Then we create a vector of this array.

The whole vector of unsigned ints can be converted to a vector of byte arrays in one transform statement. Thats quite easy. We can also copy that into a plain old C-Style array.

But this is not needed. You can use the data function of the `std::array` to access the underlying data.

This is the conversion code

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using Byte = uint8_t;
using B3Array = std::array<Byte, 3>;

std::vector <unsigned int> output = { 16383,1,8192 };
std::vector<B3Array> finalbuffer{};
Byte plainCStyleArray[3];

int main()
{
    // Convert to byte array, C++ style
    std::transform( output.begin(), output.end(),std::back_inserter(finalbuffer),
        [](const unsigned int i) {
            Byte b0 = (i >> 16) & 0xFF; Byte b1 = (i >> 8) & 0xFF; Byte b2 = (i)  & 0xFF;
            B3Array ba{ b0,b1,b2 };
            return ba;
        }
    );

    // Copy one vector to plain C-Style array (but why?)
    std::copy_n(finalbuffer[0].begin(), 3, plainCStyleArray);

    // Play a little bit. Some test code
    for (size_t i = 0; i < output.size(); ++i) {
        B3Array b3a = finalbuffer[i];
        std::copy_n(b3a.begin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can write in your function (after the `std::transform`):

```
for {unsigned i=0; i<finalbuffer.size(); ++i) {
status = SPI_Write(handle, finalbuffer[i].data(), 3, &transferCount, options);
            if (status != FT_OK)
                print_and_quit("Error while transmitting bytes.");
}
```

As you can see, I just added `.data()` to `finalbuffer[i]`

All this seems so simple so that I guess, I maybe misunderstood your question. Sorry for that . . .